# Altium Designer: Polygon does not connect to the pads on the same Net

Tags: pcb-design, altium, polygon

I'm trying to put a plane shield using polygon pour and I realized that some object is not connected to my polygon.

In the picture below it is clearly seen that the GND through hole is not connected to my polygon that is declared as "GND".

I can't understand the reason because I checked all possible causes and I wasn't able to find anything.

[image]

---

SOLVED: I restarted Altium Designer and everything is fine now.

Comment: Try manipulating option "Pour over all same net objects"

Comment: A typical cause of this is if there is another polygon overlapping this one. Even if the other polygon is shelved, it can prevent this polygon from connecting correctly. Make sure this polygon comes before any overlapping polygons (even shelved ones) in the pour order.

Comment: @ThePhoton, I believe this is the first reason. I removed all the previous shelved ones but the problem wasn't resolved until I performed program restart.

Comment: @MrBit, did you "Repour All" after removing the shelved polygons or fixing the pour order?

Comment: FYI: [Thread on Altium Live](https://forum.live.altium.com/#posts/213915/).

Comment: @ThePhoton, Yes I did. Nothing worked untill I restarted the software.

Comment: Restarting Altium was the only solution for me too.

Comment: Try this command separately ->> T + G + A
for repour, all polygon pours.

Answer (score 3):

Open *Design >> Rules >> Plane Rules >> Polygon Connect Style* page and check the connect style is relief or direct connect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running Altium Designer 21. This problem recently happened to me and it's seems to be a bug that's been around for awhile. Restarting Altium fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had to select the "Pour over all same not objects" in the polygon properties for it it connect to the vias

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the polygon is the same net name of the connections you want it to connect to. Then repour the polygon.

Comment: While this is a good thing to check in general, OP did make sure in this case: "In the picture below it is clearly seen that the GND through hole is not connected to my polygon that is declared as "GND""